# How to change the opacity on a home page hidden by a sliding menu

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova, onsen-ui

I am developing an app with :
- Cordova 6.4.0
- iOS platform 4.3.0
- Android platform 6.1.0

I have a home page (home.html) and a sliding menu (menu.html) that overlay on it.
I want the home page to be darker when the Sliding menu is open.

I am using Firefox to preview my app with the element inspector.
I can see that by default the opacity is at : "opacity: 0.9" and when I change the value to 0.6 directly in firefox in works perfectly. The menu is darker.
Firefox said that the value is in the "inline" file ? When I click on "inline" it open the index.html and I can't see the opacity value.

When I try to change the value in the app code, it doesn't change anything.

I try in several file like onsenui.js but it doesn't work.
The second file where "opacity : 0.9" is present is "onsenui_all.js" but is seems that my code doesn't use this page for building (no link in index.html).

Any help will be appreciated.

Thx a lot.

Comment: Can you specify which version of onsen UI you are using, as well as which component to create the menu ?

Comment: Hi Nikola, I have onsenUI v1.3.2.

My Menu.html use this :
        <ons-list class="list-top">
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showDetail($index)">
            <ons-row>
                <ons-col width="15%" style="color: #6071af;"> 
                <ons-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></ons-icon>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                <div style="color: #000;">
                {{item.title}}
                </ons-col>
            </ons-row> 
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>"

Comment: and I declare in a config.js the list :

"data.items = [       
        { 
            title: 'ACCUEIL',
            icon: 'fa-home',
            page: 'home.html'
        },
        { 
            title: 'PRÉSENTATION',
            img: 'img/logo_pres.png',
            icon: 'ion-person-stalker',
            page: 'about.html'
        },"

Comment: My great friend find a solution.
In onsenui.js, I set 0.7 instead of 0.1 here :

},

      _generateMainPageStyle: function(distance) {
        var max = this._menuPage[0].clientWidth;
        var opacity = 1 - (0.7 * distance / max);

        return {
          opacity: opacity
        };